# How to use/reuse the map generated in visual SLAM

Tags: computer-vision, orb, slam

I am using visual SLAM such as ORB SLAM for indoor robotcar navigation. I have a few questions hope you can help me.

1. After I generate the map, which is basically 3D points with their descriptors, how can I re-use it next time? Is it a good idea at all to reuse the map generated?
2. Support I do re-use the map, as time goes by, how can I maintain and improve the map?
3. In place where there is not much feature points, what should I do to improve the performance of visual SLAM?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There's [OpenVSLAM](https://github.com/xdspacelab/openvslam) that is based on ORB as well, and also supports loading prebuilt map. But there's no support for prebuilt map in OpenVSLAM while mapping. You should develop code for improving prebuilt map while running SLAM. If you have not much keypoints, you should look for more feature extraction methods.